# Как добавить display:none элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавить display:none элементу с классом schedule-item у которого значение атрибута data-day равно значению переменной 'v'

```js
$(".sh_day").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $(".schedule-item").css("display","none");

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно добавить [атрибут селектор](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) в выборку

```
$(".sh_day").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $(`.schedule-item[data-day="${v}"]`).css("display","none");    
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".sh_day").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $(".schedule-item").each(function(){
   if ($(this).attr("data-day")==v) {
       $(this).css("display","none");
   }
});
```

Comment: проверять нужно значение атрибута, а не элемента

Comment: @Grundy заменить val() на attr('data-day')

Comment: это один из вариантов, но лучше исправить в ответе

Comment: @Grundy ваш ответ в любом случае правильнее)

Comment: не там атрибут выбираешь :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var v = 'value';
if( $('.schedule-item').first().data('day') == v ){
    $('.schedule-item').first().css('display', 'none');
    // $('.schedule-item').first().hide();// можно так сделать display:none;
}
```

Comment: только для первого элемента вроде

Comment: Это есть ответ, а события и остальной код уже сам напишет

Comment: @user190134, как отработает твой код, если `$('.schedule-item')` вернет несколько элементов? что вернет `$('.schedule-item').data('day')` в этом случае?

Comment: точно, это же массив получится, проглядел. Поправил, для первого элемента.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".sh_day").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).attr('data-day');
  $('.schedule-item[data-day='+ v + ']').hide();
});
```

Так удобнее будет, еще и скорость можешь выставить + если нужно открыть то `show()` раз `jquery` юзаешь :)

Comment: ты скрываешь **все**, а нужно только те _у которого значение атрибута data-day равно значению переменной 'v'_

Comment: @Grundy не вчитался изначально

Comment: ошибся в строке селектора

Comment: @Grundy уже бегу домой с работы, потому спешка